# How do I make the text come up on a new activity not the same activity?

Tags: android, string, button, android-activity, public

I am using android studio and I am trying to make a list of what has been typed into the computer once the button has been pressed for it to appear on the next page. 
This code allows it to come up on the same one, but how do you make it come up on the next page when the button is clicked. (like a online shopping basket)

```
public View.OnClickListener onClick() {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: You need to start a new Activity to create a new page.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @david Would you right it like this? public View.OnClickListener onClick() { mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { Intent intent2 = new Intent(BedroomDoorSigns.this, Basket.class); startActivity(intent2); mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString())); } });

Comment: @09Emi Yes, you are getting the hang of it. Take a look at my answer, and accept it by pressing the checkmark if it helps. Feel free to ask me any other questions also!

Answer (score 0):

You need another View, another XML file, set elements (TextViews, EditTexts...) then you use this:

```
public View.OnClickListener onClick() {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.2ndlayout);                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
  String message = editText.getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

**`//To display text in other activity:`**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
textView.setText(message);
```

Thats it! Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: this is the code i used, but nothing happens when i press the button. public void sendMessage(View view) { Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { Intent intent = new Intent(BedroomDoorSigns.this, Basket.class); EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); String message = editText.getText().toString(); intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message); startActivity(intent); } }); }